# TeamViewer: Not ready. Check your connection

Tags: remote, teamviewer

I have installed TeamViewer 10 in Ubuntu 14.04 and used it with mobile Internet (USB tethering). It worked well, but once I disconnected the mobile device and connected the system to an office Internet (LAN) with Internet access, it shows this error information: `Not ready. Please check your connection`. I have checked all proxy settings but nothing worked - I need to use my office system at home through TeamViewer. How should I proceed to make TeamViewer work on LAN?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Sometimes after switching the network connection (wired/wireless), TeamViewer service hangs.
To fix this - **restart teamviewer service**. Open a terminal and execute the following commands :

```
sudo teamviewer daemon stop
sudo teamviewer daemon start
```

Alternatively you can restart the teamviewer service with : `sudo teamviewer daemon restart`
To check if the service was restarted successfully execute : `sudo teamviewer daemon status`

When it doesn't solve the problem, check if TeamViewer is blocked by the firewall of the router.
If you are working with an office system provided by a company, it may be blocked within there.

**Additional information addressing the comments under the answer "Didn't work for me" :**

Sometimes the installation of `teamviewer` by clicking the `.deb` file, which opens the Software Center, doesn't install the application including all required dependencies properly and hence fails.
Having installed and used TeamViewer successfully for many years, I can recommend to install TeamViewer by using the `gdebi` packaging tool, to install it execute `sudo apt install gdebi`. Right-click the `.deb` installation file and select to open it with `gdebi` - then start the installation.

**Update December 2017 : TeamViewer 13** was released, for the first time as a native Linux client.
The installer added a TeamViewer repository which currently seems to be not correctly configured.
This may be due to the fact that TeamViewer 13 Linux is still only available as a preview edition. To avoid apt errors, I recommend to remove the repository and install new versions manually until the issue is fixed, to achieve this execute `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list`.

**Update April 2018 :** I've tested TeamViewer 13 on **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** (running on Xorg) and the application installed correctly by clicking the `.deb` file. TeamViewer seems to work as expected.

**Update August 2018 :** **TeamViewer 13** has left the preview state and became [a regular product](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Linux/Update-13-2-13582-Summer-release/td-p/40607).

**Update November 2018 :** **TeamViewer 14** was released and is being made [available for Linux](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/).

Users who experience problems with the new edition, may want to follow the discussions in the TeamViewer - [Community TV General](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/TeamViewer-General/bd-p/TeamViewer_12) | [Community TV Linux](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Linux/bd-p/Linux) | [Community TV TeamViewer 13](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/TeamViewer-13/bd-p/TeamViewer_13).

Comment: Why is restarting sufficient?

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid][askubuntu.com/help/…](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)! **;-)**

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Also didn't work for me (whatever I tried). What work for me: Don't use the .deb archive. Download the [tar.xz](https://www.teamviewer.com/download/linux/). Extract it with `tar xvf teamviewer_i386.tar.xz`. And open the binary in a desktop environment (e.g. with vnc) `./teamviewer` Only disadvantage: You have no teamviewer service running. They seem to have messed up the .deb file

Comment: Its working for me.

Comment: I faced the same issue. Tried reinstalling using gdebi. Seemed to do nothing. I kept it running for 2 minutes. It started working just like that. Really something weird happening with teamviewer.

Comment: Linux blows....

Answer (score 3):

It did get to work in my case by running below commands in a terminal:

```
    sudo systemctl stop teamviewerd.service

    sudo systemctl start teamviewerd.service
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could get this to work is to run it as portable.

1. Download the .tar.xz version
2. Uncompress it somewhere
3. `./tv-setup checklibs` (this will tell you if all dependencies are met)
4. `./teamviewer`

Give it some time to start, it feels slower to me than the packaged version.

Answer (score 0):

You might be behind the proxy.
if so go to Extras->options->general->proxySettings->configure.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by install the following package:

```
sudo apt install libnss-resolve:i386
```

& then:

```
sudo systemctl stop teamviewerd.service
sudo systemctl start teamviewerd.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue since I installed TeamViewer 14 on my Ubuntu 18. I was able to fix it by running the following command and restarting the machine.

```
sudo systemctl enable teamviewerd.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here... it was caused by the DNS server used by the internet provider. Changing to any other made it work.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was my VPN. Teamviewer wouldnt work through it. TV has its own VPN, but not on Linux. I'm going to try AnyDesk. I dont need to stream through a VPN, but I want to be able to connect and to the PC to be able to disable it temporarily.