# libjpeg installed but teamviewer cannot locate

Tags: software-installation, shared-library, teamviewer, locate

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 multi-arch. I installed libjpeg62 via synaptic.

```
% ldconfig -p | grep libjpeg
    libjpegxr.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpegxr.so.0
    libjpeg.so.62 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62
    libjpeg.so.9 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.9
    libjpeg.so.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
    libjpeg.so.8 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
    libjpeg.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
```

Here libjpeg.so.62 is located at `/user/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` which is in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH. However, typing `locate libjpeg.so.62` does not return anything. Why?

Also, when I run teamviewer, it complains that it cannot find libjpeg.so.62 either.

**Update**: as @oranja points out, after a while `locate libjpeg.so.62` works.  But teamviewer still cannot detect it.

I don't have admin right i.e. `sudo`, but can run `gksu` with my user password. So my plan is to install all dependencies for teamviewer via synaptic, then run the .tar.gz portable version of teamviewer. Any thoughts are welcomed.

Comment: @cl-netbox : sorry I am not in sudo group. But for some reasons I can run gksu just fine. So i guess I can't install any package from command line. So far the only option I know is to run **gksu synaptic** then install necessary packages from it. Any comment would help.

Comment: @cl-netbox : I can't do that because I don't have admin right. It says "Sorry, user xxxx is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash' as root on xxxx".

Comment: @cl-netbox: it is a work PC so it is understandable that I don't have admin right. The IT guy told me to install whatever I need via **gksu synaptic**.

Comment: yet I can install packages via **gksu synaptic**, the libjpeg62 above is an example.  gksu accepts my user password, but not sudo. I guess the system admin somehow lets me use gksu, but not sudo.

Comment: Then your IT guy has to install TeamViewer for you ... tell him to do it the way as being described here -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/676224/teamviewer-not-ready-check-your-connection/676266#676266 ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes some time.
The index for `locate` is stored by default in:
`/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`

And it is updated periodically by the `updatedb` utility.

If your run `updatedb` and still `locate` doesn't find `libjpeg.so.62`, that's odd and worth checking the configuration.

As for TeamViewer, I suspect that the problem is that you installed the 32bit version of TeamViewer, which looks for 32bit version of its dependencies.

Check this support article:
https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/363-how-do-i-install-teamviewer-on-my-linux-distribution

And this question:
[Installed Teamviewer using a 64-bit system, but I get a dependency error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362951/installed-teamviewer-using-a-64-bits-system-but-i-get-a-dependency-error/363083)

*Edit:*

For **TeamViewer 12.0.71510**, `dpkg -I` reports the following dependencies:

```
libc6 (>= 2.11), libgcc1, libasound2, libdbus-1-3, libexpat1, libfontconfig1, libfreetype6, libjpeg62, libsm6, libxdamage1, libxext6, libxfixes3, libxinerama1, libxrandr2, libxrender1, libxtst6, zlib1g
```

You can either do a bulk install of all these, or install only those that TeamViewer complains about, but either way, you need to add the `:i386` specification.
So for example: `libc6` becomes `libc6:i386` and `libjpeg62` becomes `libjpeg62:i386`.
(This is also explained in the answer I've linked above, but the dependency list is outdated there).

If you have to use `synaptic`, there's an "Architecture" filter that might help to find the i386 versions of those dependencies.

Comment: thank u (up voted for answering half of my question). Now **locate libjpeg.so.62** works, but my teamviewer still cannot find it. Plz check my updated question.

Comment: I still don't have enough rep to comment on your question, but regarding `sudo` shell access, how about `gksu gnome-terminal`? This should get you a root shell, I believe.

Comment: `gksu gnome-terminal` does nothing. It just asks for password, then return to normal shell. I guess synaptic is the only app that I am allowed to run with gksu (just test `gksu gedit` and it doesn't work either). Fine, I just install all dependencies with synaptic then. Thank you for pointing out the list of dependencies. I verify that all are installed except libjpeg62:i386 and libxtst6:i386. The teamviewer log file also complains it cannot find these libraries. Searching for these libraries on synaptic returns nothing. Looks like they completely disappear from Ubuntu16.04???

Comment: It should be there, at least according to the official package index: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libjpeg62 ; It is also possible to download it directly and then figure out how to install it: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/libjpeg62/download